# String aggregation using JSON in SQL Server 2016

Tags: sql, json, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2016

I would like to format a json string `'[{"_":7},{"_":13},{"_":17}]'` as `'[7,13,17]'`
Tried with REPLACE Method in TSQL. I have to use REPLACE method three times to get the desire result.

```
SELECT REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE('[{"_":7},{"_":13},{"_":17}]','},{"_":',', '),'{"_":',''),'}','')
```

is there a better way to do that?
I am using SQL Server 2016.

After some comments for this post, This my actual issue.

I have some customer data. Customer Table

```
CustomerId | Name
    1         ABC
    2         XYZ
    3         EFG
```

each customer has some area of interest. Customer Area of Interest

```
CustomerAreaInterestId | FK_CustomerId | FK_AreaOfInterestId
      1                       1            2
      2                       1            3
      3                       1            5
      4                       2            1
      5                       2            2
      6                       3            3
      7                       3            4
```

Area of interest table

```
   AreaOfInterestId | Description
       1                Interest1
       2                Interest2
       3                Interest3
       4                Interest4
       5                Interest5
```

In the final result set, I have to include area of interest id's as an array of value

```
[
{
    "CustomerName": "ABC",
    "AreaofInterest": "[2,3,5]"
},
{
    "CustomerName": "XYZ",
    "AreaofInterest": "[1,2]"
},
{
    "CustomerName": "EFG",
    "AreaofInterest": "[3,4]"
}
]
```

The result consists with some other data’s as well. I have omitted for the code brevity.

Comment: You are neither formatting nor replacing. You're *querying* an array of objects, extracting the property values and returning them as an array themselves. You need to write a query for this

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I was follwing his approch to generate that output. https://stackoverflow.com/a/42778050/764369

Comment: This has nothing to do with *JSON*. You're asking how to aggregate strings in SQL Server 2016. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3672860/134204) to that question shows the correct query, although it's *not* that different from the common XML method. No replacement needed,

Comment: Post the *actual* problem, *actual* data and *actual* output. If you have a problem with that query's results, adding extra REPLACE statements won't fix the problem.

Comment: You need *fewer* replacements, not more. The linked answer works for *string* values, which are quoted. You're asking how to work with *numeric* values which aren't. You need to remove some quotes. Or just use the XML technique

Comment: You need to cast the numeric field to text before using the concatenation query. Replacements won't work. The generated *JSON* string doesn't have a closing double quote

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Short Version**

Cast the numeric field to text before trying to aggregate it

---

From the comments, it looks like the *real* question is how to use JSON to aggregate strings in SQL Server 2016, as shown [in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3672860/134204).

```
SELECT 
 JSON_VALUE(
   REPLACE(
     (SELECT _ = someField FROM someTable FOR JSON PATH)
    ,'"},{"_":"',', '),'$[0]._'
)
```

or, rewritten for clarity :

```
SELECT 
 JSON_VALUE(  REPLACE(
                    (SELECT _ = someField 
                     FROM someTable 
                     FOR JSON PATH)
              ,'"},{"_":"',', ')
 ,'$[0]._')
```

That query works *only* with string fields. One needs to understand what it does before it can be adopted to *other* types.

- The *inner query* generates a JSON string from a field's values, eg `'[{"_":"value1"},{"_":"value2"}]'`.
- `REPLACE` replaces the quotes and separators between objects, changing that array of objects to `'[{"_":"value1,value2"}]'`. That's a single object in an array, whose single attribute is a comma-separated string.
- `JSON_VALUE(...,,'$[0]._')` extracts the `_` attribute of that single array item.

That trick can't be used with numeric values because they don't have quotes. The solution is to cast them to text first:

```
SELECT 
 JSON_VALUE(  REPLACE(
                    (SELECT _ = CAST(someNumber as nvarchar(20))
                     FROM someTable 
                     FOR JSON PATH)
              ,'"},{"_":"',', ')
 ,'$[0]._')
```

Eg :

```
declare @t table (id int)
insert into @t 
values
(7),
(13),
(17)


SELECT 
   JSON_VALUE(   REPLACE(
                        (SELECT _ = cast(ID as nvarchar(20)) 
                         FROM @t 
                         FOR JSON PATH)
    ,'"},{"_":"',', '),'$[0]._')
```

The only change from the original query is the `cast` clause.

This produces :

```
7, 13, 17
```

This conversion is localized so care must be taken with decimals and dates, to avoid producing unexpected results, eg `38,5, 40,1` instead of `38.5, 40.1`.

**PS:** That's no different than the XML technique, except `STUFF` is used there to cut off the leading separator. That technique *also* needs casting numbers to text, eg :

```
SELECT STUFF(
    (  SELECT N', ' + cast(ID as nvarchar(20)) 
       FROM @t FOR XML PATH(''),TYPE)
    .value('text()[1]','nvarchar(max)'),
    1,2,N'')
```

Comment: Very well explained. I have updated the question based on your request.

Comment: In my testing with a big dataset, and including a `WHERE` clause in the `SELECT` statement to aggregate detail records per master record, the `FOR JSON` version is about 20% faster than `FOR XML`, and doesn't have issues with encoding special characters like & and > etc.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to use only `JSON` functions (not string-based approach), the next example may help:

```
DECLARE @json nvarchar(max) = N'[{"_":7},{"_":13},{"_":17}]'
DECLARE @output nvarchar(max) = N'[]'

SELECT @output = JSON_MODIFY(@output, 'append $', j.item)
FROM OPENJSON(@json) WITH (item int '$."_"') j

SELECT @output AS [Result]
```

Result:

```
Result
[7,13,17]
```

Of course, the approach based on string aggregation is also a possible solution:

```
DECLARE @json nvarchar(max) = N'[{"_":7},{"_":13},{"_":17}]'

SELECT CONCAT(
   N'[',
   STUFF(
      (
      SELECT CONCAT(N',', j.item)
      FROM OPENJSON(@json) WITH (item int '$."_"') j
      FOR XML PATH('')
      ), 1, 1, N''
   ),
   N']'
)
```

Comment: The OP is already trying to use a string aggregation technique based on JSON

Answer (score 1):

Yes you could do it with only 2 replace :

```
SELECT REPLACE(REPLACE('[{"_":7},{"_":13},{"_":17}]','{"_":',''),'}','')
```

[**DEMO HERE**](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2016&fiddle=5dff579eb161ff7b9eeb9eab6d57570c)

Except if you really need a space after coma which is not what you asked to be honest.

Comment: Most people need some space after a [coma](https://medical-dictionary.thefreedictionary.com/coma). It takes a while for the brain to adjust to being awake again.